# Inferring generic types in nested constructors

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I'm hitting a problem with a TypeScript project. I have a generic `Processor` that performs validation and processes data by accepting `Validator` and `Executor` objects which are also both generic, inferring their arguments from the `Processor`:

```
type ExecutorFunction<Args extends any[], Return extends any> = (...args: Args) => Return;

class Validator<Args extends any[]> {
  private validators: ExecutorFunction<Args, boolean>[] = [];

  constructor(...validators: ExecutorFunction<Args, boolean>[]) {
    this.validators.push(...validators);
  }

  validate(...args: Args): boolean {
    return this.validators.every((validator) => validator(...args));
  }
}

class Executor<Args extends any[], Return extends any> {
  private executors: ExecutorFunction<Args, Return>[] = [];

  constructor(...executors: ExecutorFunction<Args, Return>[]) {
    this.executors.push(...executors);
  }

  execute(...args: Args): Return[] {
    return this.executors.map((executor) => executor(...args));
  }
}

class Processor<Args extends any[], Return extends any> {
  private validators: Validator<Args>[] = [];
  private executors: Executor<Args, Return>[] = [];

  constructor(...args: (Validator<Args> | Executor<Args, Return>)[]) {
    args.forEach((item) => {
      if (item instanceof Validator) {
        this.validators.push(item);

        return;
      }

      this.executors.push(item);
    });
  }

  process(...args: Args): Return[] {
    return this.executors.flatMap((executor) => executor.execute(...args));
  }

  validate(...args: Args): boolean {
    return this.validators.every((validator) => validator.validate(...args));
  }
}
```

This works fine for simple cases, but if I add a `Validator` that accepts other validators (an `OrValidator` for example) the child `Validator`s lose their generic value:

```
class OrValidator<Args extends any[]> extends Validator<Args> {
  constructor(...childValidators: Validator<Args>[]) {
    super((...args) =>
      childValidators.some((validator) => validator.validate(...args))
    );
  }
}

class NumberProcessor extends Processor<[number, number, number], number> {}

const numberProcessor = new NumberProcessor(
  new Validator((a) => a > 0),
  new Validator((a, b) => b > 10),
  new Validator((a, b, c) => Number.isFinite(c)),
  new OrValidator(
    new Validator((a) => a > 0),
    new Validator((a, b) => a > b), // This and the line below error because it only expects 1 argument
    new Validator((a, b, c) => c < 99)
  ),
  new Executor((a, b, c) => (a + b) * c)
);
```

I'd like the `OrValidator` to correctly pick up the `NumberProcessor`s generic values, am I doing something wrong/missing something obvious?

[Link to codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-vkvrsp?file=/index.ts)

---

After fixing the missing `...` spread operator, the examples where I manually add the generic types to each nested items do work as expected, but the original question still stands as to why this isn't inferred automatically for the nested items.

Comment: This code example is at the very least missing the fact that `childValidators` should probably be a rest parameter, right?  If not, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @jcalz Ah, sorry about that, I omitted the `...` when creating the example! The problem is still present though. I've updated the codesandbox too.

Comment: So [contextual inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) doesn't happen arbitrarily deeply.   It's hard to say exactly how deep (implementation details of the compiler are ‍♂️).  If you only want to know why this happens, I might be able to find sources for the fact that there *are* limits but not necessarily what they are.  That's assuming your question is "why is this happening" and not "is there some refactoring that gives better inference", which would require a different sort of effort to address.  What, specifically, is the question?

Comment: @jcalz I guess my question is "am I doing anything wrong" and it looks like the answer is "no but there are limits" which is good enough for me. Adding the generics to the `Or`s, `Not`s and `And`s as per nullables answer (in my current implementation I just have all the types redefined in the first `ValidatpeFunction`) is fine but felt like extra cruft I could do without. If you'd like to add an answer elaborating on the limits and why they exist is be happy to accept. Thank you for your time on this!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the infer of the functions inside the constructor of `OrValidator`.

Change them to

```
const numberProcessor = new NumberProcessor(
  new Validator((a) => a > 0),
  new Validator((a, b) => b > 10),
  new Validator((a, b, c) => Number.isFinite(c)),
  new OrValidator(
    new Validator((a, b, c) => c < 99),
    new Validator((a) => a > 0),
    new Validator((a, b) => a > b),
  ),
  new Executor((a, b, c) => (a + b) * c)
);
```

Or type the `new OrValidator`:

```
const numberProcessor = new NumberProcessor(
  new Validator((a) => a > 0),
  new Validator((a, b) => b > 10),
  new Validator((a, b, c) => Number.isFinite(c)),
  new OrValidator<[number ,number, number]>(
    new Validator((a) => a > 0),
    new Validator((a, b) => a > b),
    new Validator((a, b, c) => c < 99),
  ),
  new Executor((a, b, c) => (a + b) * c)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My current approach is to define the types for all the arguments in the first `ValidatorFunction` argument to the first `Validator` in a combinator, so that's not a problem to do. Redefining the generic argument is a fine solution too so I'll stick to what I'm doing for now I think. Thanks for taking the time to answer!